# How can I pass a value from a new Activity to an old Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using two Activities, **Old Activity** and **New Activity**. I want to pass a value from **New Activity** to **Old Activity**. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

an example::

```
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("newPicPosition", position);              
            Intent intent = new Intent(NewActivity.this, OldActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
```

use **setResult()**

> **public final void setResult (int
> resultCode, Intent data)**  Since: API
> Level 1  Call this to set the result
> that your activity will return to its
> caller.
>
> Parameters::
>
> **resultCode**  The result code
> to propagate back to the originating
> activity, often RESULT_CANCELED or
> RESULT_OK
> **data**  The data to propagate
> back to the originating activity.

Comment: thanks Josrgesy,
But i have one doubt,i can't get value from new activity,i am using 
 Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
       String s=b.getString("name");
       Log.v("name",s);  how can i get value?

Comment: ok I have posted how you can get the values from new activity =)